# find and replace only the first match in PowerSell

Tags: powershell, replace, select-string

I want to replace:

```
"created_at"
```

with

```
"`r`ncreated_at"
```

but only the first time that occurrence in each line.

This is my code:

```
$regex="`"created_at`""
Get-Content twittermsgs.txt |%{$_-replace "`"metadata`"","`r`n"}|$regex.Replace($s, "`r`n`"created_at`"", 1)>testtwit1.txt
```

But I have errors and I don't know what to do.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @user3562182, you should give us an example that we can run ourselves. We don't even know what is in twittermsgs.txt. The best thing you could do would be to try to find the simplest possible form of the problem. Make a simple example that still shows the problem, that we can run ourselves. If you do that, then that will make it more likely someone will help you, but also when you go through that process, you will often discover the solution to the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this will do it:

```
Get-Content twittermsgs.txt |%{
    $_ -replace "`"metadata`"","`r`n"|%{$_ -replace  "^(.*?)(`"created_at`".*$)","`$1`r`n`$2"}
}>testtwit1.txt
```